# Roots of a Quadratic Equation

Tags: c++

So I am trying to write  aprogram that would calculate roots of a quadratic equation. This is what i came up with. The first possibility so (D > 0) works, but others don't. I can't find a mistake in my code. Could you please help me? Thank you!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float x1;
    float x2;
    float D=b*b-4*a*c;
    float realPart;
    float imaginaryPart;

    cout << "Write a: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Write b: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Write c: " << endl;
    cin >> c;


   //first possibility D > 0
   if (D > 0){
      x1=(-b+sqrt(D))/(2*a);
      x2=(-b-sqrt(D))/(2*a);
      cout << "Results are: x1: " << x1 << " and x2 " << x2 << endl;
    }
   //second possibility D < 0
   else if (D < 0){
      realPart = -b/(2*a);
      imaginaryPart = (sqrt(-D))/(2*a);
      cout << "First result: " << realPart << " + " << imaginaryPart << "i" 
      <<endl;
      cout << "Second result: " << realPart << " - " << imaginaryPart << "i" 
      << endl;
    }
   else if (D == 0){
      x1=(-b)/(2*a);
      cout << "Result is: " << x1 << endl;
    }
   else
       cout << "THERE'S A MISTAKE!" << endl;

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Read the code from top to bottom. You are asking the computer to calculate D before knowing what a,b,c are. I'm voting to close as this is a simple error that has nothing to do with quadratic equations.

Comment: oh i think i get it. so i should write float a; float b; float c; then cout << "write a" blah blah blah and then float D=b*b-4*a*c. right?

Comment: Exactly. The answer by Bathsheba below explains this in more detail.

Comment: You can also use only `float D;` first (declaration) and then later `D = b*b-4*a*c` (without the `float`, i.e., assignment to the variable).

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Complete beginner here, so i really appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can accomplish your intention of predefining the result of

```
D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
```

*before* `a`, `b`, and `c` are known<sup>1</sup>, this is not what is happening in your case.

The simplest thing to do here is to calculate the descriminant `D` after `a`, `b`, and `c` are known. I.e. move the statement further on in your program. Currently the behaviour of your program is undefined.

---

<sup>1</sup>One way is to use *actors*.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Complete beginner here, so i really appreciate the clarification!

Comment: @luchka13: If you are starting out then ditch the idea of using a `float`. These days they are rarely faster, and can even be slower due to the repeated float -> double -> float conversions that CPUs have to make.

Comment: yeah i started with double but then i thought that it doens't want to calculate because of i used double instead of float. Thanks, will use double from now on.